# Python sqlite 3. Efficient Origin-Destination Trip Matrix

Tags: python, sqlite

I already make a good matrix trip but it takes to much time (12 hours). Here is what I did:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('trips.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.commit()

for station_O in stations_origin:
    lista_station = list()
    lista_station.append(station_O)

    for station_D in stations_destination:
        cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM etapas_metro WHERE par_subida = ? and par_bajada = ? AND tiempo_subida BETWEEN '2019-08-07 06:00:00' AND '2019-08-07 11:59:59'", (station_O,station_D,))
        lista_station.append(cursor.fetchone()[0])

    with open('Matrix.csv', 'a') as archivo_escritura:
        writer = csv.writer(archivo_escritura)
        writer.writerow(lista_station)
```

The problem is that look all de trips in the bd more than ones. (check the matrix as many times as the length of the list `station_origin`).

The bd is just a huge database of trips with a lot of information.

Comment: For example, in station_origin i have [A,B,C] and in station_destination = [E,F,G].
So in the database, I have per row:

A-E
A-E
A-F
B-E
C-F
...
So, python looks if in the first column there is an "A", then a "B" and then a "C". For that reason, the program has to check three times (in this case) all the data.
My question is if there a way to just check the database ones.

P.D Sorry for my English, I'm a Spanish spoken man from Chile :)

Comment: "problem is that look all **the**  trips in the bd more than ones"

Comment: The task is to calculate the matrix trip like:
    E  F   G \\
A  2  1   0  \\
B  1  0   0  \\
C  0  1   0  \\

Comment: In the same example above. In the database I have rows like this:
A to E \\
A to E \\
A to F \\
B to E \\
C to F \\
the column of origin has the name "par_subida" and the destination column has the name "par_bajada"

Comment: hope now is more clear :)